# Remove link from selected references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using the `hyperref` package, but I would like a way to use `\ref` without making it into a link (but not always).  To give an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section} \label{section}

The following is a list placed in Section~\ref{section}:
\begin{enumerate}[1]
    \item
        first list item
    \item \label{item}
        second list item
    \item
        third list item
\end{enumerate}
From my point of view the most interesting is part of this list is part \ref{item}.
\end{document}
```

My situation is something like this: I would like `hyperref` to make a link to the section when I write `\ref{section}`, but I do not want it to do so when refering to the label `item`, becuase the reference to this label will be place in the same place as the list, and if I refer a lot to the points in the list, then the text will be perforated with links, which looks stupid.

Is there a way to select which references are made into links?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is documented in the `hyperref` manual.

Just use `\ref*` for those labels that you do not want to become links, eg `\ref*{item}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section} \label{section}

The following is a list placed in Section~\ref{section}:
\begin{enumerate}[1]
    \item
        first list item
    \item \label{item}
        second list item
    \item
        third list item
\end{enumerate}
From my point of view the most interesting is part of this list is part \ref*{item}.
\end{document}
```