# Selectively turn off hyperref links for citations

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

I'm using both the `natbib` and the `hyperref` packages.  I would like to be able to selectively not generate hyperlinks for some of the in-text citations.  I know that I can use the asterisk with `\ref*{...}` in order to prevent a hyperlink from being generated for that reference, but adding an asterisk changes nothing with `\cite*{...}`.

I see that [Selectively turn off hyperref links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/selectively-turn-off-hyperref-links?rq=1) and [Remove link from selected references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81890/remove-link-from-selected-references) describe how to selectively disable hyperlinks for cross-references, and [How to turn on/off certain types (e.g. citation, url, file) of hyperref links?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116338/how-to-turn-on-off-certain-types-e-g-citation-url-file-of-hyperref-links) describes how to disable ALL hyperlinks of a given type, but neither of these address my problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Environment `NoHyper` should help:

```
\begin{NoHyper}\cite{foobar}\end{NoHyper}
```

A star form is problematic, because some citing commands already have one (e.g. `\citep`, `\citet`). But macros can be defined, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\nolink}[1]{%
  \begin{NoHyper}#1\end{NoHyper}%
}

\nolink{\cite{foobar}}
```

Answer (score 11):

Heiko's answer is great. However, it doesn't work inside captions, for instance. To make it work, use:

```
\newcommand*{\nolink}[1]{%
  {\protect\NoHyper#1\protect\endNoHyper}%
}
```

The curly braces inside are important.