# How to prevent colored cite links (hyperref) within tikz node [fill=black, text=white] to reset text color to black?

Tags: hyperref, bugs

The following MWE should demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{companion,
        author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
        title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
        date         = 1994,
        edition      = 1,
        publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
        location     = {Reading, Mass.},
        pagetotal    = 528,
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
        sorttitle    = {LaTeX Companion},
        indextitle   = {LaTeX Companion, The},
        shorttitle   = {LaTeX Companion},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolang=other,
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,
    final=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=yellow,
%   linkcolor=blue,
%   anchorcolor=purple,
%   urlcolor=green,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=100mm,
        text width=10cm,
        align=center,
        fill=black,
        text=white,] {\huge 
            %\hypersetup{citecolor=green}
            Hello World!
            \cite[p. 100]{companion}

            Where am I? %you are there, but invisible due to wrong text color

            \textcolor{white}{Ahh, hello again!}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
I have two problems:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Manually resetting the textcolor is inefficient and

\item
even if the textcolor is reset right after the cite command the text until the cite's closing bracket ', p. 100]' is not affected (it remains invisible).
\end{enumerate}

Question: Is there a comfortable solution to get the cite mark colored?

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? My build environment: Win7-64, Texlive 2017, luaLaTeX

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118195/36296

Comment: @samcarter placing the cite command in a NoHyper-environment, eliminates the coloring of the link: e.g. `\hypersetup{citecolor=green}` does not work anymore (thus the name nohyper, I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCG coloured links generated with the `ocgx2` package (TeXLive-2017, MiKTeX) seem to fix both reported problems, with the bonus of OCG colour links printing on paper in the current text colour, `white` here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{companion,
        author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
        title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
        date         = 1994,
        edition      = 1,
        publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
        location     = {Reading, Mass.},
        pagetotal    = 528,
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
        sorttitle    = {LaTeX Companion},
        indextitle   = {LaTeX Companion, The},
        shorttitle   = {LaTeX Companion},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolang=other,
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    %backref=true,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,
    final=true,
%    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=yellow,
%   linkcolor=blue,
%   anchorcolor=purple,
%   urlcolor=green,
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=100mm,
        text width=10cm,
        align=center,
        fill=black,
        text=white,] {\huge 
            %\hypersetup{citecolor=green}
            Hello World!
            \cite[p. 100]{companion}

            Where am I?

            %\textcolor{white}{Ahh, hello again!}
            Ahh, hello again!
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

%\noindent
%I have two problems:
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item
%Manually resetting the textcolor is inefficient and
%
%\item
%even if the textcolor is reset right after the cite command the text until the cite's closing bracket ', p. 100]' is not affected (it remains invisible).
%\end{enumerate}
%
%Question: Is there a comfortable solution to get the cite mark colored?

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't heard about ocg[x|-p|x2] yet. Thx!

Comment: OCG is the technical term for PDF Layers; option `ocgcolorlinks` defines one layer for printing, another one for viewing on screen and places different colours for links on these layers.

Comment: `hyperref` provides `ocgcolorlinks` too, but produces the same erroneous result as  its plain `colorlinks` option.

Comment: So it's a bug in hyperref, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like so.